# Singleton for different NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I always used for connect with Server singleton class. I didn't check response from server and easy take data. Now I need use 10 different requests. I create property NSURLConnection. So how can I identify what connections I use in delegate methods like

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Because from each request I take different data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is have a custom connection class representing a connection, its data, and optionally some info about the connection. I use this:

```
@interface MyConnection : NSObject

@property NSURLConnection *connection;
@property id info;
@property NSMutableData *data;

@end
```

Then just put the connections in an array, and compare the actual NSURLConnection objects to each other, in order to find out which connection received data/failed etc.

Creating a connection:

```
 NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:someRequest delegate:self];

    if (connection){
        MyConnection *con = [[MyConnection alloc] init];
        con.connection = connection;
        con.data = [NSMutableData data];
        [self.arrayWithConnections addObject:con];
    }
```

The methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    MyConnection *con = [self getConnection:connection]
    [con.data appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    MyConnection *con = [self getConnection:connection];
    [con.data setLength:0]; 
}

-(MyConnection *)getConnection:(NSURLConnection *)con
{
    for (MyConnection *myCon in self.arrayWithConnections)
        if ([con isEqual: myCon.connection])
            return myCon;
    return nil;
}
```